# Unable to Run Docker Image Build Command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning the docker , but don't know where i am going wrong.

Running the following command for the creating the Image from the Dockerfile:

Command: I am inside the the terminal where project is located and running below command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t spring-boot-docker-ex .
```

Error Message:

```
time="2020-02-02T11:23:46+05:30" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: unable to upgrade to h2c, received 500"
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpuse
tmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=rveuxbqxdbzktl94h1jxp2s26&shmsize=0&t=docker_test&target=&
ulimits=null&version=1: context canceled
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:latest
ADD target/dockerlearn-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar dockerlearn.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","dockerlearn.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: try disabling 'experimental features' in preference panel for docker. Also if you are running on windows, pl make sure you've opened cmd as administrator

Comment: @ankidaemon it's already disabled.

Comment: docker daemon restart is also required if this was missed after enabling/disabling preferences.

Comment: @ankidaemon it's automatically popping up for the restart ,after enabling/disabling.

Comment: when i am changed my command to this -docker image build -t docker_test_4 "E:\DockerProj\dockerlearn",i am able to create the image but when i change the version of image then i get the same message as above . But i can't figure out why dot is not working i.e this command - docker image build -t docker_test_4 .